# The most efficient way to checking value types in a list

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list that contains lists. For example:

```
lst = [1, 2, 'c', [4, 5], 'f', ['g', 'h', 'i']]
```

I want to find the indices of the lists in `lst` (in `lst` is would be 3 and 5).

What I have so far:

```
lst_idx = [lst.index(val) for val in lst if type(val) is list]
```

However, my actual data has thousands of lists, each with thousands of elements, so the above list comprehension is taking a lot of time. Is there a way to do in some vectorized form? Ideally, I want some kind of mask of length `len(lst)` that takes True if list else False.

Comment: the issue isn't vectorization, it's that you are using a quadratic time algorithm. don't use `.index` in a loop.

Comment: `[isinstance(val, list) for val in lst]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The central problem here is not the size of the sub-list; that should be immaterial.  Rather, it's that you have chosen to look up the position of a list that you already have in hand.  Get rid of that expensive `index` call: *that* is expensive when used on a long sub-list.  Just keep track of where you are.

```
lst_idx = [idx for idx, val in enumerate(lst) if type(val) is list]
```

Also consider replacing `type(val) is list` with `isinstance(val, list)`